# Compiler error C3538 in Visual Studio using std::bind

Tags: c++11, lambda, visual-studio-2015, stl

I have problems to compile the following small code fragment. Visual Studio 2015 has problems in the deduction of the type of `remover`. Can someone explain me why and how to fix this error?

My idea was to create a reuseable function deleting the first occurence of a value in a given STL container under some user definable predicate.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
auto removeOnlyOnce = [](std::vector<T>& v, const std::function<bool(const T&)>& pred) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), pred);
    if (iter != v.end()) {
        v.erase(iter);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,2,2,3 };

    // Works
    std::function<bool(const int&)> isTwoPred = [](int x) { return x == 2; };
    removeOnlyOnce<int>(v, isTwoPred);

    // Also works
    removeOnlyOnce<int>(v, [](const int x)->bool { return x == 2; });

    // Gives compile error: C3538
    // auto remover = std::bind(removeOnlyOnce<int>, v, std::placeholders::_1);
    // remover([](const int x)->bool { return true; });

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

The compiler issues the following warning:

```
main.cpp(26): error C3538: In einer Deklaratorliste muss "auto" immer in denselben Typ hergeleitet werden.
main.cpp(26): note: kann "<lambda_d00b55a1f2cac59f0efd4a81f45edea3>" sein
main.cpp(26): note: oder "std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,<lambda_d00b55a1f2cac59f0efd4a81f45edea3> &,std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,const std::_Ph<1> &>"
    with
    [
        _Ty=int
    ]
```

Compiling with Wandbox and Option C++11 gives the following warning, which might be important:

```
prog.cc:8:6: warning: variable templates are a C++14 extension [-Wc++14-extensions]
auto removeOnlyOnce = [](std::vector<T>& v, const std::function<bool(const T&)>& pred) {
     ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: It compiles with `clang++`

Comment: That is very interesting! Maybe there is problem with Visual Studio.

Comment: I meant that it compiles with `clang++` after removing the `&` in `removeOnlyOnce` (which obviously won't work)

Comment: I just removed the & and updated my question. Still it is not compiling.

Comment: I tried by myself. Copying my source to WandBox made the code to compile, but in Visual Studio it is really not compiling. There is some ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lambda is not local. Please omit the `&` in `[&]` and you should be fine. Maybe a little cryptic, what I wrote: In other words, you don't have a `this` to capture.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately it doesn't resolved my problem.

Comment: After the edit it became obvious. Yes 2015 is lacking most of c++14.

Comment: This was not so obvious to me. What would be a possible workaround? Is there any?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017?